# python translate string.punctuation meaning

Tags: python-3.x

What does `line.translate((None, string.punctuation))` do and what does it mean?

```
import string
ahmed = open('whatever.txt')
counts = dict()
for line in ahmed:
    line = line.translate((None, string.punctuation))
```

Comment: do you understand the difference between: `f(a,b)` and `f((a,b))` in Python?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a code example for Python 2, `str.translate` used to take a second argument `deletechars` that would remove all presence of those characters from the string (here, it means deleting all punctuation):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate:

> `str.translate(table[, deletechars])`
>
> Return a copy of the string where all characters occurring in the optional argument deletechars are removed, and the remaining characters have been mapped through the given translation table, which must be a string of length 256.

In Python 3, this argument was removed as part of the API of `str.translate`, now characters to be deleted are mapped to `None`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate:

> `str.translate(table)`
>
> Return a copy of the string in which each character has been mapped through the given translation table. The table must be an object that implements indexing via **getitem**(), typically a mapping or sequence. When indexed by a Unicode ordinal (an integer), the table object can do any of the following: return a Unicode ordinal or a string, to map the character to one or more other characters; return None, to delete the character from the return string; or raise a LookupError exception, to map the character to itself.

Comment: actually, `line.translate((None, string.punctuation))` is wrong on Python 2 and it doesn't raise an error on Python 3 because the tuple has `__getitem__` method (but the result is unhelpful e.g.: `"\0\1".translate((None, "a")) == "a"` (`U+0000` is deleted, `U+0001` is replaced with `"a"`)). Notice double parens.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: my guess is either an accidental copy-paste, or `line.translate(*(None, string.punctuation))`